# How to select at most N rows based on column value from an excel sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an excel sheet like so:

[image: Sample Excel Sheet]

| Name | Title | Company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N1 | T1 | C1 |
| N2 | T2 | C1 |
| N3 | T3 | C1 |
| N4 | T4 | C2 |
| N5 | T5 | C3 |
| N6 | T6 | C3 |
| N7 | T7 | C3 |
| N8 | T8 | C3 |
| N9 | T9 | C3 |
| N10 | T10 | C4 |
| N11 | T11 | C4 |
| N12 | T12 | C5 |
| N13 | T13 | C5 |
| N14 | T14 | C6 |

I want to be able to filter out at most N (say N=2) records from each company.

In our example above, this would mean getting an output:

| Name | Title | Company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N1 | T1 | C1 |
| N2 | T2 | C1 |
| N4 | T4 | C2 |
| N5 | T5 | C3 |
| N6 | T6 | C3 |
| N10 | T10 | C4 |
| N11 | T11 | C4 |
| N12 | T12 | C5 |
| N13 | T13 | C5 |
| N14 | T14 | C6 |

Is there any way to do this other than sorting by the company name and manually selecting records? Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: would you accept a google apps script solution?

Comment: Excel or Google sheets? Update your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Player0's formula didn't seem to work for me, at least not in Sheets.  My apologies if I just did something wrong with it.

But this variation of it did work for me in Google Sheets, if anyone encounters the same issue.

```
=FILTER(A2:C,ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAYFORMULA(if(C2:C<>"", COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(C2:C), "<="&ROW(C2:C)),))<3))
```

I hope this is helpful.

[image]

Comment: I was trying to use COUNTIF too. Then I filtered manually. But putting it into an arrayformula and filter is pretty neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER(A2:C, COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(C2:C), "<="&ROW(C2:C)<3))
```